# Clipped contents of Flex DataGrid are indicated by null" instead of trailing dots

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, localization, locale

[image]

My Flex app uses a DataGrid. Clipped cell contents are indicated by trailing dots. This works fine in English language. When we launch the browser in a different language (say Portugese), the cell contents are indicated by "null" instead. Any clues?

Comment: Which version of Flex are you using? Is it any other language or just a few? The pt_PT locale was [added in v4.9.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33164); I imagine pt_BR may only be available in an even more recent version. That said, there should be a default instead of no value at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my SWF was compiled with English version of framework resource property files. As per design, Flex cant load framework property files in runtime.

Workaround this by specifying English as fall back language.

```
resourceManager.localeChain=[myLocale,"en_US"];
```